# Set fully qualified domain name on EC2 instance

Tags: networking, dns, amazon-ec2, hostname, puppet

I am trying to set a fully qualified domain name on EC2 instance. I have set CNAME entry in Route53, so when I go to sync1.staging1.mycompany.net, it resolves to the correct instance.

What I have done so far without success, I have edited */etc/hostname* (so it stays the same after restarting):

```
sync1.staging1.mycompany.net
```

I have then used hostname command to set the hostname:

```
sudo hostname sync1.staging1.mycompany.net
```

I have then edited */etc/hosts* and made sure this line is there:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost sync1.staging1.mycompany.net sync1
```

The problem is, when I run *hostname -f*, I get:

```
localhost
```

When I run *hostname -s*, I get correctly:

```
sync1
```

When I run just *hostname* without parameters, I get:

```
sync1.staging1.mycompany.net sync1
```

The problem is I am trying to run a Puppet manifests which needs the fully qualified domain name to be set, otherwise I am getting an error when I run *puppet apply manifests/site.pp*:

```
Error: Could not find default node or by name with 'sync1.eu-west-1.compute.internal, sync1.eu-west-1.compute, sync1.eu-west-1, sync1' on node sync1.eu-west-1.compute.internal
Error: Could not find default node or by name with 'sync1.eu-west-1.compute.internal, sync1.eu-west-1.compute, sync1.eu-west-1, sync1' on node sync1.eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

This is EC2 instance running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Any ideas? Do I need to set and elastic IP address for the instance in order for it to have the fully qualified domain name?

Answer (score 2):

hostname -f will return the first name after 127.0.0.1

So simply switching localhost and your fqdn will give you a correct return address while the localhost alias will still work.

Comment: I just tried adding 'foo' as the first token after 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts then ran `hostname -f`, it did not affect anything.

Comment: Same with modifying /etc/hostname. Keep in mind I did not reboot or force a hostname reload with hostname -F, so I wouldn't expect a change in /etc/hostname to affect anything.

Comment: I think Ubuntu changed the default internal address, it uses here now 127.0.1.1
The trick will be the same but now you add foo as first name in the 127.0.1.1 line, no restart of anything required.